# Hovering colors issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Can you please tell me why does hovering near the social icons turns them black? Is it because of the navbar buttons? Can get rid of this black hovering and keep only blue/red hovering? https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/16537/

```
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right social">
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-2x fa-facebook hidden-xs"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-2x fa-twitter hidden-xs"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-2x fa-instagram hidden-xs"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-2x fa-pinterest hidden-xs"></i></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
</nav>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to override the default bootstrap styles in your css file:

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
  color: #777;
}
```

and remove

```
.navbar-default .navbar-brand:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-brand:focus {
  color: #000;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/16540/

Answer (score 0):

Alright, after inspecting the source with developer tools, I found out the problem is with the bootstrap classes themselves.

For instance, if you toggle the hover state on the navbar links, it's immediate child will get a color of black. We have to override Bootstrap's default behavior.

```
.navbar-default li a:hover > *, .navbar-default li a:focus > * {
  color: #777;
}
```